# How do i use an API? getting nothing back in a AJAX(jQuery) request

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

i am figuring out how i can use the tumblr api, but i think i maybe doing it wrong

i tried

```
$.get("http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=tumblr", function(data) {
    $("body").prepend(data);
});
```

and even $.ajax()

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    contentType: 'json',
    url: 'http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/api/read/json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

and i got nothing. but when i go to the [url](http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/api/read/json) in the browser, i get something, whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't give a name to the callback function if you are using an anonymous callback. Leave the naming to jQuery using `callback=?`:

```
$.getJSON('http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

This way the actual request will look something like this:

```
http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=jsonp1284885664340
```

Answer (score 0):

Your get() call is missing the second parameter (the parameters to your call). So, your call should be something like:

```
$.get("http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/api/read/json", {callback:'tumblr'}, function(data) {
  $("body").prepend(data);
});
```

I tested it, but it does not work here. My guess is that the call to http://jiewmeng.tumblr.com/api/read/json checks if the call is an AJAX request and returns nothing if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax only works on the same host as the page, if you want to call page (via ajax) on different host you must write php proxy, read [this article](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html).

You can also set dataType to "jsonp", this will fetch json request not by XHR but with script tag.

Comment: but how do i use an API if thats the case? proxy is the only way?